# Render a tooltip if an error validation message exists

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip, message

**If I have this tooltip:**

```
<p:tooltip for="code" hideEffect="fade" showEffect="fade" >
    <p:message for="code" />
</p:tooltip>
```

How can I do to show the tooltip box only if exists an error validation message?

Currently my tooltip looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still needs this. This works with JSF 2.2 PF 5.0

```
<p:tooltip id="toolTipContent" for="code" trackMouse="true" 
  rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList and not empty facesContext.getMessageList('form:code')}">
    <p:message for="code" />    </p:tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rendered Attribute and check if there is an error-message for this element:

```
rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList('code')}"
```

Comment: Not going to work. This condition will fail because it will always evaluate to false on first render (and not be subsequently ajax-updated)